# numpy sum of unsigned and signed number becomes floating point

Tags: python, numpy

Why the answer is floating point? I thought it should be an integer.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.uint64(12)
12
>>> np.uint64(12) + int(4)
16.0
>>>
```

Comment: This is certainly unexpected.

Comment: Well, at least the result is consistent with `np.promote_types(np.uint64, np.int)`. I found a [related issue on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a recent [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/384wqz/numpy_why_cant_numpy_cast_uint_in_int/).

This is the way Numpy functions are designed to return consistent values for the whole range of input data.

Both 16-bit unsigned and signed integers would fit into int32, therefore

```
>>> np.uint16(4) + np.int16(5)
9
```

However for uint64 and int64 the smallest datatype that would fit all possible values is float64.